# Can I access multiple schemas with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

could someone please give me a suggestion? My schema example looks like this:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  eventName : String,
  date: Date,
  location: String,
  role: [],
  task:[],
});


const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: String,
  eventList: [eventSchema],
});
```

I'm even wondering about creating a 3rd schema and put it into the eventSchema. Do you think it's possible to work on?

So far, I only access the userSchema through

```
const ModelClass = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports = ModelClass;
```

Could I somehow export the other schemas and access them directly at the same tiem? How is that done? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can most definitely use multiple schemas with mongoose, all at the same time (mine has 18 right now, with 5 more models in the works).  I would recommend putting them in separate files, so you can export each one individually, then import them any place you need them.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't it screw up the access? I mean how could the different events still be part of the userSchema if it's in a different file?

Comment: That's what the import statements do, pulls in the code you reference.  just make sure to do an export in each file and you'll be able to import and use it in any file you need to

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: You were right, it works perfectly. Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple Schema's in Mongoose is perfectly possible.  The best approach I've seen is to create each schema in a separate file (so you can export each one). Then you can import and consume them anywhere you need.